# Remove last portion of the NSURL: iOS

Tags: iphone, ios6, ftp, nsstring, nsurl

I am trying to remove just the last part of the url, Its a FTP URL.

Suppose, I have a URL like: > ftp://ftp.abc.com/public_html/somefolder/. After removing the last portion I should have it as: ftp://ftp.abc.com/public_html/.

I have tried using `stringByDeletingLastPathComponenet` and `URLByDeletingLastPathComponent`, but they dont remove the last portion correctly. They change the entire looks of the url.

for instance, after using the above said methods, here is the URL format i get ftp:/ftp.abc.com/public_html/. It removes one "/" in "ftp://", which is crashing my program.

How is it possible to removve just the last part without disturbing the rest of the URL ?

**UPDATE:**

```
NSURL * stringUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURL * urlByRemovingLastComponent = [stringUrl URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSLog(@"%@", urlByRemovingLastComponent);
```

Using above code, I get the output as :- ftp:/ftp.abc.com/public_html/

Comment: `-stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` will indeed condense any double slashes. The documentation for it does explicitly call out that it's only intended for paths, and not URLs, though!

Comment: `-URLByDeletingLastPathComponent` does its job properly though. The only I can see for your above code sample to output `ftp:/ftp.abc.com/public_html/` is if the input was similarly malformed as something like `ftp:/ftp.abc.com/public_html/somefolder/`

Comment: Quick followup: turns out on OS X 10.6 (and presumably iOS 4) `-URLByDeletingLastPathComponent` mishandles double slashes in the path portion. Trying to remove such a component leads to `../` being appended instead

Comment: One random thought: is it possible your input URL from the text field actually includes a trailing newline character? It turns out that prior to OS X 10.9 and iOS 7, the last character can be an invalid one. I imagine this could screw up path editing logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now try

```
    NSString* filePath = @"ftp://ftp.abc.com/public_html/somefolder/.";

    NSArray* pathComponents = [filePath pathComponents];
    NSLog(@"\n\npath=%@",pathComponents);
    if ([pathComponents count] > 2) {
            NSArray* lastTwoArray = [pathComponents subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([pathComponents count]-2,2)];
            NSString* lastTwoPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:lastTwoArray];
             NSLog(@"\n\nlastTwoArray=%@",lastTwoPath);

            NSArray *listItems = [filePath componentsSeparatedByString:lastTwoPath];
            NSLog(@"\n\nlist item 0=%@",[listItems objectAtIndex:0]);

     }


output

path=(
      "ftp:",
      "ftp.abc.com",
      "public_html",
      somefolder,
      "."
      )

lastTwoArray =somefolder/.

list item 0 =ftp://ftp.abc.com/public_html/
```

Comment: This indeed works, but the URL can be anything, What if it is
ftp://ftp.abc.com/public_html/somefolder/someOtherFolder/ ?
This method wont yield correct results.

Comment: ohhh.. i think url is fixed. just wait

Comment: Thank you Samir. though your answer did not server my question, I had to find other solution. 
But, still.. I used your solution for other purpose.

Answer (score 20):

Hmm. URLByDeletingLastPathComponent works perfectly given the above input.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://ftp.abc.com/public_html/somefolder/"];
NSLog(@"%@", [url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]);
```

returns

```
ftp://ftp.abc.com/public_html/
```

Do you have some sample code that is yielding improper results?

Max

Comment: @Max: Please check the Update in my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate the bug you're having. Is it possible that the string input is malformed?

Comment: @Max: I am not sure but, I am providing the input from TextFields.

Comment: What happens when you NSLog(@"%@", string); just before trying to remove the last path component?

Comment: It does give the correct format of the URL. which is the string that I entered through the textfield

Answer (score 1):

An example of how to extract the last part of NSURL. In this case the location of the file. Sqlite core data

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreAPI.sqlite"];

NSString *localPath = [storeURL absoluteString];

NSArray* pathComponents = [localPath pathComponents];

NSLog(@"%@",[pathComponents objectAtIndex:6]);

NSString * nombre = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pathComponents objectAtIndex:6]];
```

This code returns me the name of the file CoreAPI.sqlite